# MySQL cuts off string from subquery which uses UDF

Tags: mysql, sql, string, subquery, user-defined-functions

I have rather big InnoDB table (~100k rows) in MySQL 5.6 and UDF function:

```sql
CREATE AGGREGATE FUNCTION collect RETURNS STRING SONAME 'libcollect.so';
```

When I query

```sql
SELECT collect('CASES:10,DROP:10', shipment_bucket_code, weight) FROM d_shipments;
```

`"83.140000,2513.910000,4439.710000,1764.100000,7852.960000,98.920000,828.620000,2346.950000,1566.620000,107594.130000"` will be result and it's right.

But if I call UDF in subquery

```sql
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT collect('CASES:10,DROP:10', shipment_bucket_code, weight) FROM d_shipments
) as sub;
```

result will be `"83.140000,2513.910000,4439.710000,1764.100000"`. String was cut off by top-level query. It's confirmed by UDF debugging.

Also if I use these queries on small table, everything works correctly. The same when using built-in functions like `CONCAT("83.140000,2513.910000,4439.710000,1764.100000,7852.960000,98.9", "20000,828.620000,2346.950000,1566.620000,107594.130000")`

In the course of reason search I came across a [similar old non-fixed bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=29202).
Whether there is any workaround to it? It seems that MySQL's subquery string result is restricted with size of some buffer, because string cutting always happens equally.

**UPD**: Currently finded workaround is to rewrite subqueries as JOINs.

**UPD2**: ...but it worked not in all queries. Probably, bug is reproduced on rather big tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found workaround: explicit returned value type casting

```sql
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 
        CAST(collect('CASES:10,DROP:10', shipment_bucket_code, weight) AS CHAR(255))
    FROM d_shipments
) as sub;
```

Probably, it allows to allocate needed memory size for returned string. I didn't look in mysql sources, but something prompts to me that a problem in weak typing of returned strings (and DECIMALs) from UDF.